# How to remove blurred background of images?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, image-segmentation, roi

I am working on a project of leaf disease classification. I want to remove the blurred background of my entire dataset using an efficient machine learning segmentation algorithm. The output should be the colored version of ROI. And due to the huge volume of the dataset I want an algorithm with less training time. So, could you suggest me any option I may stick to?

The dataset sample is attached below.

[leaf image with a disease symptom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9F2r.jpg)

Comment: Same question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45054587). It is not a simple task. Since both your ROI and background excessively green, many procedures need to be tried as the link mentions. I can suggest edge detection and segmentation will be a good starting point.

Comment: You can check these two implementations for an idea from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/change-the-background-of-any-video-with-5-lines-of-code-7cc847394f5d) and [learnopencv](https://learnopencv.com/applications-of-foreground-background-separation-with-semantic-segmentation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular problem isn't too difficult to solve. It's not as bad as it could be since there's only one foreground object which means we can solve it using simple methods. @Ceopee's instinct of edge detection is the correct one since it's the most obvious way that the foreground will differ from a blurry background.

I grayscaled the image and use a Canny edge detector. I didn't really tune it at all so we get a bunch of edges, but we only care about finding the edges of the leaves. Thankfully, we don't have to spend a bunch of time tuning it for each image since we only care about the biggest continuous edge.

[image]

I dilate the image to connect up nearby edges (canny gives 1 pixel wide lines which are easily disconnected) and then use findContours to get an outline of all of the white lines. I sort through and pick the biggest contour by area and use that one to create a mask.

[image]

The jaggedness of the mask bothers me so I do an opening operation (to cut off thin jaggies) followed by a median blur (to smooth out the edges).

[image]

Then all there is to do is use the mask to crop out the image and it's done. (I had to change it to a jpg to make the 2mb limit so there might be some compression artifacts on here).

[image]

Here's the code (Note this is in OpenCV 3.4, if you're using a different major version then you'll have to modify the findContours line)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("leaf.jpg");

# grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# canny
canned = cv2.Canny(gray, 0, 100);

# dilate to close holes in lines
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.dilate(canned, kernel, iterations = 1);

# find contours
# Opencv 3.4, if using a different major version (4.0 or 2.0), remove the first underscore
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# find the biggest contour
biggest_cntr = None;
biggest_area = 0;
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour);
    if area > biggest_area:
        biggest_area = area;
        biggest_cntr = contour;

# draw contours
crop_mask = np.zeros_like(mask);
cv2.drawContours(crop_mask, [biggest_cntr], -1, (255), -1);

# opening + median blur to smooth jaggies
crop_mask = cv2.erode(crop_mask, kernel, iterations = 5);
crop_mask = cv2.dilate(crop_mask, kernel, iterations = 5);
crop_mask = cv2.medianBlur(crop_mask, 21);

# crop image
crop = np.zeros_like(img);
crop[crop_mask == 255] = img[crop_mask == 255];

# show
cv2.imshow("leaf", img);
cv2.imshow("gray", gray);
cv2.imshow("canny", canned);
cv2.imshow("mask", crop_mask);
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

If you want to generalize this to include multiple foreground objects you could filter the contours by size and reject contours smaller than a certain threshold.

Comment: Nicely done! +1 for improving my view

Comment: I am trying to apply an adaptive thresholding for the Canny thresholds on Ian Chu's above code (since I am working on a bunch of images in the dataset), but I can't due to cv2.adaptiveThreshold() function returns an array of values. I will appreciate if I can get a solution on how to apply adaptive thresholding on canny edge detection.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding over what adaptiveThreshold does. It applies thresholding to an image, it returns a black and white mask. Canny also returns a black and white mask so adaptive thresholding probably won't do anything to the canny mask. If you have further work for this project you should open a new question since this one has been closed.